# How to correctly return the HTTP status code 404 for an error page in Nuxt project

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, http-status-code-404, response-headers

If you request the URL https://www.sistrix.com/I-do-not-exist/, we have no content for that page. As
the requested page does not exist and therefore has no content, our web server will show you an error
page in the header it shows 304 as the status code that was not correct. how to show 404 as the status
code in the header.

This my Code

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="error-template">
          <a href="/">
            <img
              class="mainlogo"
              alt="Company logo"
              style="margin-bottom: 11px"
              src="https://ik.imagekit.io/your_imagekit_id/rest-of-the-path.jpg"
            />
          </a>
          <h3 style="color: gray">Oops!</h3>
          <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 401">Page not found</h1>
          <h1 v-else>An error occurred- {{ statusCode }}</h1>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="statusCod in statusCode" :key="statusCod.id" class="item">
              <nuxt-link :to="'/statusCode/' + statusCod.id">{{ statusCod.statusCode }}</nuxt-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <img alt="company shot" style="width: 20%" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/your_imagekit_id/rest-of-the-path.jpg" />
          <div class="error-actions">
            <nuxt-link style="font-size: 17px" to="/">Home page</nuxt-link>
          </div>
        </div>
        strong text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from '@nuxtjs/axios'
export default {
  layout: 'blog',

  props: ['error'],
  asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const { rest } = axios
      .post(`http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTHZjyGrPC?indent=2`)
      .then((res) => {
        return { statusCode: rest }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
      })
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.error-template {
  padding: 14% 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.error-actions {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.error-actions .btn {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.mainlogo {
  max-width: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I've edited your code, please check that it's fine as this since there were few errors (especially a useless `async asyncData` because you're not using `await`).

Answer (score 0):

If you directly go to the 404 page, you should get some successful code like `200` because you actually properly reached it.

If you go to something like `https://www.sistrix.com/nice-fake-url`, you should have a 404 error and then redirect the user to the `error` layout.

Also, what is `http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTHZjyGrPC?indent=2` ?

Comment: It is /Notfound Rest API . It Return 404 status code.

Comment: **Really** not sure of what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: When user trying to  non existing page in URL that time I just need to show the 404 as the statuscode  to the user in HTTP header .For SEO Optimization.

Comment: @kissu It's very clear what he's trying to achieve. He wants the response status code to be 404, not 200.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tricky way, you will serve your 404.html from your server. If user wants to go something not exist url then you will redirect him to your error layout (404) and after that you will redirect him again to 404.html which is serving from your server.

Long story short; firstly he gets 304 or 200 and after that he gets 404.

Note: if you guys want to track the 404 url's that is entered by users, you can do it with a query string. before redirection you can do something like that  https://www.sistrix.com/404.html?path=nice-try